# garbage collector does not work

Tags: java, arraylist, garbage-collection

I have a program that download stocks data from the internet and then create a Stock objects that contains a stock meta data and an array of historical prices.

At first I ran over more then 20000 stocks created them and entered them into an arraylist for writing them to the db(all of them in one transaction). this wasn't a good idea and before i ended to download all the stocks i wanted the program died because of OutOfMemory.

Then i decided that after every 500 stocks that i am adding to the arraylist i will write them to the DB and clean the arraylist(arraylist.clear() for GC to make it's "magic") and then fill the arraylist with another new 500 Stocks and go through the same proccess all over again.

That didn't work either, and my program died again because of an OutOfMemory Exception.

I thought that the problem may be in some where else in my code and I made an experiment and ran the same code but one little difference: after i create each Stock object i do not put it into the arraylist and i just continue and create Stock objects all over again without adding them into the arraylist.

The result was that my program didn't consume almost any memory at all and that make me really confused and frustrated.

**Please help me find out if something is wrong with my program**.

Here are some lines of the code:

The first version:

```
ArrayList<Stock> stocksData = new ArrayList<Stock>();
Stock stock;

BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(YAHOO_STOCKS_SYMBOLS));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] stockMetaData = line.split(CSV_SPLIT);
        stock = new Stock();
        if (stockMetaData.length >= 4) {
            stock.setSymbol(stockMetaData[0]);
            stock.setName(stockMetaData[1]);
            stock.setExchange(stockMetaData[2]);
            stock.setCategory(stockMetaData[3]);
            DATA_UPDATER.updateStockData(stock, fromDate, toDate);
            if (stock.getHistoricalData() != null
                    && stock.getHistoricalData().size() > 0) {
                stocksData.add(stock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the second version:

```
ArrayList<Stock> stocksData = new ArrayList<Stock>();
Stock stock;

BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(YAHOO_STOCKS_SYMBOLS));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] stockMetaData = line.split(CSV_SPLIT);
        stock = new Stock();
        if (stockMetaData.length >= 4) {
            stock.setSymbol(stockMetaData[0]);
            stock.setName(stockMetaData[1]);
            stock.setExchange(stockMetaData[2]);
            stock.setCategory(stockMetaData[3]);
            DATA_UPDATER.updateStockData(stock, fromDate, toDate);
            if (stock.getHistoricalData() != null
                    && stock.getHistoricalData().size() > 0) {
                stocksData.add(stock);
            }
        }
        if (stocksData.size() == 500) {
            WritingUtils.getInstance().updateStocks(stocksData);
            stocksData.clear();
            // I also tried
            //System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

Im adding some more information:

Stock fields:

```
protected String _symbol;

protected String _name;

protected String _exchange;

protected Date _upToDate;

protected ArrayList<DailyData> _historicalData;
```

DailyData fields:

```
private Date _date;

private double _open;

private double _close;

private double _adjClose;

private double _high;

private double _low;

private double _volume;
```

Comment: I assume you mean `ArrayList.clear()` not `ArrayList.clean()`. You don't show where in your code you are calling this method.

Comment: I fixed it. i showed the first version of my code. I will post the second.

Comment: First, this code does not show any splitting into 500 batches and cleaning. Second, this is not showing what happens in the life cycle of the ArrayList. Between being filled and being cleared it is passed to other methods. You'll need to show those methods, too, to make sure all references to the data are cleaned up. Also, what's inside a stock?

Comment: The references to those objects(all of the stocks in the array list) should clean up because the updateStocks method just stores the data in the DB and returns nothing. Am I wrong?

Comment: Before providing a solution, I want you to try this in your if section where you are checking the size.                                                                               if (stocksData.size() == 500) {
            WritingUtils.getInstance().updateStocks(stocksData);
            stocksData.clear();
            stocksData = null; 
            stocksData = new ArrayList<Stock>();
        }

Answer (score 1):

First I would start by profiling the application with a tool like [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) (which comes with the JDK) and pinpointing exactly what objects are being retained in the heap.

Second, there is no '`clean()`' method on `ArrayList`, so its not clear what you actually did to prevent your list from growing indefinitely.

Lastly, consider setting a conditional breakpoint in your program to 'catch' when the List is growing beyond your expectation.

EDIT: If what you're asking now is :

'Can my OutOfMemoryError be due to the fact that:

```
protected ArrayList<DailyData> _historicalData;
```

is growing and contributing to the memory pressure?'

The answer is yes.  Have you also tried to increase the memory to your process?  Try running:

`java -Xms1g -Xmx1g *yourProgram*`

to see if it still fails.  You may not have a leak, it may just be that your application needs more memory for what you are doing.

Comment: I used it now and saw that the object that consume most of the memory is a DailyData object that each stock has something like 1000 DailyData objects. ohhhh I just thought about a reason that clearing the Stock array wouldn't be enough. I think I should also clear each one of the arraylist of DailyData that each individual Stock has! It's True???

Comment: There is nothing in your code above about DailyData, so there is no way for me to know...

Comment: In response to what you just suggested, the heap size grew to almost 2GB(The default maximum in java 1.8). I can't make it larger.

Comment: Did you actually try to set it explicitly?

Comment: I mean that i can't afford that my application would consume more then 2GB of memory.